# Using network in flex sdk 4.5 gives blank swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I developed a flash app and i need the functionality when I click on a sprite I want to open a web page in browser for example http://www.google.com. I use flex sdk 4.5 and I changed the use-network tag from false to true in flex-config.xml. But when i compile my project and load the swf in browser I get everything blank. I tried also to use html page with swf embeded but same result

Any idea why it is doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May you need to add the location where the SWF is stored as a trusted location [HERE](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).

Comment: ...but please check if it works to call a other domain then the domain the SWF is loaded from when using on a webpage!

Comment: If the generated SWF is used on a webpage it is possible (I don't know so check) that you are not allowed to access other domains then the domain the SWF is loaded from and the "trusted locations" won't help you there...

Comment: Yup I tried to create location like "http://localhost/br/" and the swf is emebed in index.php but I see blank page.